# Simple way of drawing a filled arrow/triangle for use as item bullet

Tags: beamer, symbols, itemize

I'd like to draw a filled arrow and use it as an `item` bullet in [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer).

I already managed to draw the line with

```
\rule[0.5ex]{0.6ex}{0.6ex}
```

but I can't create the arrowhead. I though about using the character which is used as default for `subitem`s, but how is it called?

So basically I want these two stitched together:

[image]

and vertically centered with the text.

In Powerpoint the little dude looks like:

[image]

and equals the character 198 of the **Windings 3** font.

There is also the **unicode-character 25B8**, but I don't know how this could be applied for a solution.

I'm looking for a very basic way and definitely want to avoid [tikz](/questions/tagged/tikz).

**If I could use the same *custom character* in normal text, it would be great!**

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{raisedsquare}{\rule[0.5ex]{0.6ex}{0.6ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[raisedsquare]
\item First item

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\item Second item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bbding}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{raisedsquare}{\rule[0.5ex]{0.6ex}{0.6ex}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{boldarrow}{\ArrowBoldRightShort}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[raisedsquare]
\item First item

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[boldarrow]
\item Second item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{boldarrow}{\raisebox{0.3ex}{\resizebox{1.2ex}{1ex}{\ArrowBoldRightShort}}}
```

[image]

Comment: with some tweaking it seems a good option: `\scalebox{1.5}[0.7]\ArrowBoldRightShort`! Feel free to include it in your answer.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Certainly. Let your imaginations loose. :-). I have added another tweak.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two versions with the standard item in between.  The first uses essentially beamers definition for the standard item triangle.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{compoundarrow}{\rule[0.5ex]{0.6ex}{0.6ex}%
  \scriptsize\raise2pt\hbox{$\!{\blacktriangleright}$}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{tikzarrow}{\tikz{\node[single
arrow,scale=0.2,inner sep=2ex,fill] at (0,0) {};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[compoundarrow]
\item First item

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
\item Second item

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[tikzarrow]
\item Third item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```